# Trygonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

√3 cos4x+sin4x=√2
I solved equations like this one earlier by dividing with a number for example 2 so that I can change √2/2 for sin45°. However, since I have √3 too I don't see how it could work.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\cos \frac{\pi}3=\frac12, \quad \sin \frac{\pi}3=\frac{\sqrt{3}}2.
$$

Comment: We appear to be in degrees.

Comment: Then one may just note that $\frac\pi3\:\text{rd}=60^°$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\sqrt3\cos4x+\sin4x=2(\sin60^\circ\cos4x+\cos60^\circ\sin4x)=2\sin(4x+60^\circ)$$